# Creating a Connector - Query results refreshing in the same page

Tags: import.io

When creating a connector, in 'Recording a query', I follow two steps:
1-Accepted the User Agreement;
2-Executed a query.

The result is shown in the same page (without reloading), so import.io does not understand that the query has happened. Any workarounds?

Thanks a lot,
Renato

Comment: When you say "Execute a query", can you specify what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like when using the Connector, you are not inputing any text as a query. This is required for the Connector to finish recording.

One workaround you could do is hit the record button first. Then enter the URL of the webpage you wish to grab the data and push enter. Afterwards, click on Accepted the User Agreement. Lastly, Execute the query.